# Could not parse input as a floating point

Tags: tikz-pgf

Could not parse input as a floating point, how can I fix this error?

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.47]
\begin{axis}[
    ymin=0,ymax=3]
\def\w{2.5^2};
\def\k{1.55};
\def\n{1.45};
\addplot[blue,domain=0:2,samples=100]  {10*log10*(1+(x*\k/(2*pi*\n*\w))^2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `*` after `log10`, correct would be `log10(...)` instead.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.47]
\begin{axis}[
    ymin=0,ymax=3]
\def\w{2.5^2};
\def\k{1.55};
\def\n{1.45};
\addplot[blue,domain=0:2,samples=100]  {10*log10(1+(x*\k/(2*pi*\n*\w))^2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

compiles.